# Why does html() lose class-assignments?

Tags: jquery

I am debugging a problem in a web-app where an AJAX-fn returns a modified `table` that is supposed to replace existing content. That table has 4 classes listed in its `class`-attribute, but only 3 of them survive. I tried to build a repro for this case and ended up loosing all classes!

Pls. check out my example. The `predData`-table, as you can see in the first line of JS, uses these classes: `table table-sm table-bordered mt-4`. Yet, if you inspect the injected table - it has none of them! What am I doing something wrong?

```js
function Filltable(){
$("#predData").html('<table class="table table-sm table-bordered mt-4" id="predData"><thead><tr><th style="width:3em;"></th><th>ShoeSize</th><th class="pg1 text-nowrap">Point Estimate (Height)</th><th class="pg2">Lower Conf</th><th class="pg2">Upper Conf</th><th class="pg3">Lower Pred</th><th class="pg3">Upper Pred</th></tr></thead><tbody id="tbp" data-v="1"><tr><td class="text-right"><span><span id="rpr_1_1">1</span></span></td><td><input type="number" name="rpr_1_2" id="rpr_1_2" class="w-100 form-control" value="[Null]"/></td><td class="pg1"><input type="text" class="text-right form-control w-100" disabled="disabled" name="rpr_1_3" id="rpr_1_3"/></td><td class="pg2"><input type="text" class="text-right form-control w-100" disabled="disabled" name="rpr_1_4" id="rpr_1_4"/></td><td class="pg2"><input type="text" class="text-right form-control w-100" disabled="disabled" name="rpr_1_5" id="rpr_1_5"/></td><td class="pg3"><input type="text" class="text-right form-control w-100" disabled="disabled" name="rpr_1_6" id="rpr_1_6"/></td><td class="pg3"><input type="text" class="text-right form-control w-100" disabled="disabled" name="rpr_1_7" id="rpr_1_7"/></td></tr></tbody><tfoot><tr><td colspan="7"><span id="id339056085"><span class="text-success fas fa-plus-circle"></span></span></td></tr></tfoot></table>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="Filltable()">
Fill Table
</button>
<table id="predData">

</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because You want to append table to table#preData. Use div instead of table where to append your html.

```js
function Filltable(){
$("#predData").html('<table class="table table-sm table-bordered mt-4" id="predData"><thead><tr><th style="width:3em;"></th><th>ShoeSize</th><th class="pg1 text-nowrap">Point Estimate (Height)</th><th class="pg2">Lower Conf</th><th class="pg2">Upper Conf</th><th class="pg3">Lower Pred</th><th class="pg3">Upper Pred</th></tr></thead><tbody id="tbp" data-v="1"><tr><td class="text-right"><span><span id="rpr_1_1">1</span></span></td><td><input type="number" name="rpr_1_2" id="rpr_1_2" class="w-100 form-control" value="[Null]"/></td><td class="pg1"><input type="text" class="text-right form-control w-100" disabled="disabled" name="rpr_1_3" id="rpr_1_3"/></td><td class="pg2"><input type="text" class="text-right form-control w-100" disabled="disabled" name="rpr_1_4" id="rpr_1_4"/></td><td class="pg2"><input type="text" class="text-right form-control w-100" disabled="disabled" name="rpr_1_5" id="rpr_1_5"/></td><td class="pg3"><input type="text" class="text-right form-control w-100" disabled="disabled" name="rpr_1_6" id="rpr_1_6"/></td><td class="pg3"><input type="text" class="text-right form-control w-100" disabled="disabled" name="rpr_1_7" id="rpr_1_7"/></td></tr></tbody><tfoot><tr><td colspan="7"><span id="id339056085"><span class="text-success fas fa-plus-circle"></span></span></td></tr></tfoot>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="Filltable()">
Fill Table
</button>
<div id="predData">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm actually using a framework that did the .html(), but it turns out I misunderstood its doc - which clearly stated that it would replace "content of" (and not the whole entity, as i assumed)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to insert a `table` to a `table#preData` mate! Please use `replaceWith()` instead of `.html()` :)

Answer (score 0):

You should replace just table contents (`tbody` for instance) instead of the entire `table` tag:

```js
function Filltable(){
$("#predData").html('<thead><tr><th style="width:3em;"></th><th>ShoeSize</th><th class="pg1 text-nowrap">Point Estimate (Height)</th><th class="pg2">Lower Conf</th><th class="pg2">Upper Conf</th><th class="pg3">Lower Pred</th><th class="pg3">Upper Pred</th></tr></thead><tbody id="tbp" data-v="1"><tr><td class="text-right"><span><span id="rpr_1_1">1</span></span></td><td><input type="number" name="rpr_1_2" id="rpr_1_2" class="w-100 form-control" value="[Null]"/></td><td class="pg1"><input type="text" class="text-right form-control w-100" disabled="disabled" name="rpr_1_3" id="rpr_1_3"/></td><td class="pg2"><input type="text" class="text-right form-control w-100" disabled="disabled" name="rpr_1_4" id="rpr_1_4"/></td><td class="pg2"><input type="text" class="text-right form-control w-100" disabled="disabled" name="rpr_1_5" id="rpr_1_5"/></td><td class="pg3"><input type="text" class="text-right form-control w-100" disabled="disabled" name="rpr_1_6" id="rpr_1_6"/></td><td class="pg3"><input type="text" class="text-right form-control w-100" disabled="disabled" name="rpr_1_7" id="rpr_1_7"/></td></tr></tbody><tfoot><tr><td colspan="7"><span id="id339056085"><span class="text-success fas fa-plus-circle"></span></span></td></tr></tfoot>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="Filltable()">
Fill Table
</button>
<table id="predData" class="table table-sm table-bordered mt-4">

</table>
```

You can also use a div to hold the table to replace the entire table contents

```
<div id="tableHolder"></div>

$("#tableHolder").html('<table>...</table>');
```